# Cookies & Email Clients

Tags: php, cookies, html-email

I'm trying to track emails with use of a web beacon & cookies. I'm sending an html email that contains:

```
<img src='http://www.example.com/emails/create.php&email=$recipient' width=1 height=1 border=0>
```

create.php is as follows:

```
qry("insert into email_tracking (`email`) values ({$_GET['email']}')");
setcookie('testcook', date('Y-m-d G:i:s'), time()+60*60*24*30 );
```

The script and query seem to run ok as i am getting entries in my db but the cookies doesn't seem to be being created...

any help much appreciated.

ta

j

Comment: I don't believe email clients care about cookies. You may send cookies to them, but probably they ignore cookies (as there is nothing in email-related protocols related to cookies). Any reason why you want to send a cookie to the email client?

Comment: its to keep a track of views of emails sent to customers. As email clients are able to render html like browsers I assumed they might also allow cookie creation but i can't seem to get it to work. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cookies, as far as I know, cannot be set within an email client.

I'm not a PHP man myself, but if you wanted to track opens you would add a transparent .gif to the bottom of the email with the query info on the src url, and add the PHP to track it where you are hosting the images.

To track clicks, the best way to do this is have all your src urls directed to a single page with unique ids so that you can redirect them to the page they originally requested, and use that ID and redirect to count as a click for that particular link, obviously this then will count as a click on that link for every time someone is redirected to that specific page.

Sorry that I can't provide you with the code for this, but this is how you would do it, I'm fairly sure this is the way that companies such as campaign monitor, mailchimp and adestra track their emails.

Answer (score -1):

Use [`session_start();`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) before you send headers.

Comment: eh? whats session_start() got to do with cookies? ... btw the cookie sets ok if i call the script directly in a browser its just when it's called via the web beacon in a email client that it doesnt work..ta